# Can folder ids change in google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm writing an app that relies deeply on google drive folder ids. I haven't found any information about the possibility of this folder ids to change over time because of google internal changes, etc... Do anybody know if there's any information about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ids should change over time and that applies to both files and folders. Unfortunately, that has happened once for a specific subset of the files but it shouldn't happen anymore.